# Get VM Arguments using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'd like to know if it is possible to get the VM arguments using JNI?

Using the Invocation API allows you to specify the VM arguments if you are creating your own JVM.

What I'd like to be able to do is query these arguments in JNI from an already running JVM that has been lauched using the normal Java launcher. I believe that it must be possible because JMX is able to do so.

I've searched quite extensivley for this and as yet have not found a solution.

Thanks in advance
CND

PS. I know it is possible to query these using RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments() but I need to do this natively in JNI.

Comment: You can call this method from JNI. i.e. call back into Java.

Comment: I'm aware that I can make the callback into Java and use RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments() - but as I suggested in the post, I need to do this using native calls and not by calling back into Java

Comment: Can you say why? Many built in JNI calls do this so if this is a problem in your system you are likely to have other issues. Another option is to call a method with the Input Arguments when you load the library as they will not changed.

Comment: Because the application needs to detect certain input arguments and if found - disable application features. It would be too easy to circumvent this by changing the RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments() to return an empty list and recompile. Hence why I want to "hook" into the native functions to query the InputArguments. Not foolproof, but a little harder to "hack". Hope this clarifies it a bit? Thanks, CND

Answer (score 0):

RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments() calls through to VMMangementImpl.getVmArguments which returns an immutable collections, making it difficult to tamper with.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/management/sun/management/VMManagementImpl.java.htm

It in turn calls a native method getVmArguments0() and the source for this method is available in the OpenJDK.  You might be able to call whatever this method calls.